# Can I recover from a Google penalty by removing directory which is affected?

Tags: seo, google

Assume that following are path of my website.

1. `example.com/blog`: You can find all blog posts here.
2. `example.com/forum`: You can find all forum posts here.
3. `example.com/tools`: You can find all tools here.

The forum directory has user generated content. If Google penalized this website because of low quality user generated forum posts, can I recover from the Google penalty by removing the forum directory from my website?

Comment: Of course. But then again, you can simply police your forum. Keep in mind that penalties are not lifted quickly. Prevention is worth a pound of cure.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks... Yes I am moderated all posts.... So there are no very dangers posts like spams... But many are low quality. It is really hard moderated them.I mean if I removed them forum will be just empty forum....

Comment: Yes. I do get it. One of the services I provided when I was in the tech business was seeding website forums. It is real work. The real trick is getting users that elevate the standard that new users wish to emulate. My people were experts just like on this site. Otherwise, the conversations can deteriorate to junk quite easily. Also opening the topics too wide invite unfocused questions and answers. It is a balancing act for sure! Encourage the experts with real answers and detail. Also, do not be afraid to create some users for yourself and friends that can operate as seeds from time to time.